# Output from webpack to more files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Is there some option to bundle react core and my scripts separately? 
for example two files:

1. `bundle-ract.js` ( include react, react-dom, redux, immutable)
2. `bundle.js` ( my application and scripts )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there's such way. You have to define multiple entries in your webpack config. Similarly to this:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'SubItems': './src/modules/sub-items/sub.items.module.js',
        'UniversalDiscovery': './src/modules/universal-discovery/universal.discovery.module.js',
        'MultiFileUpload': './src/modules/multi-file-upload/multi.file.upload.module.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].module.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Resources/public/js'),
        library: ['eZ', 'modules', '[name]'],
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['Resources']),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                ecma: 6
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: I add externals to my webpack config and add external react libraries

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>



 but now i have error 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined"
 
there 

import React from 'react';


export default class PureComponent extends React.Component {

Comment: You have to be sure they're loaded before your scripts.

Comment: I made some change and it works !! thank you for your help